# Ceiling Fan and Light Fixture Don't Work

Tags: ceiling-fan, light

I last used my ceiling fan and light fixture in early January 2024. Both worked properly. The unit is operated with a simple remote control.
When I attempted to turn the light fixture on last week, neither the fan nor the light would turn on.  I can hear a clicking noise in the unit when I press the remote on both the fan and the light options and I can see a blue light on the remote indicating that the remote is working.  I have checked the power switch and turned the circuit breaker off and on. Neither seems to impact the problem.
Wondering if I need a new fan/light unit or if there may be an electrical problem?

Comment: Have you swapped out the batteries in the remote to be sure that it isn't the issue. Yes, you heard some response from the fan, but it is possible weak signal is "confusing" it. Start troubleshooting with the simple stuff first. Is there instructions to pair the remote to the fan? That might be an issue with the functionality being "Mismatched".

Comment: there should not be any kicking. It uses solid state relay

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, not every, but all after 1994

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact from the web, just look it up